# Using `FilePattern`/wildcards in the Shake functions `want` and `need`

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

The functions `want` and `need` both require that their input is of type `FilePath` rather than `FilePattern`. The filenames of my outputs and inputs follow a distinct pattern, outputs are `_build/*checker.sh` and the inputs are of `./*.py`. Therefore I would rather do a `want` of the form:

```
want ['_build/*checkers.sh']
```

than

```
want ['_build/dbchecker.sh', '_build/henk_checker.sh', ..., '_build/derp_checker.sh']
```

I tried building a more complex `want` by combining `getDirectoryFiles, action, need` but that doesn't work since `getDirectoryFiles` returns `Action [FilePath]` rather than `FilePath`.

What would be the proper solution to this problem?

Comment: Note that making `want` take a list of patterns has been requested, see https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/144. However, I don't think it's a good idea, because as you discovered in your answer, often you want to `want` a transformation over a pattern, not the results of the pattern itself.

Comment: @NeilMitchell, maybe these kind of transformations are a nice example for in the manual/tutorial. I often need these kind of transformations. It could serve as an example of a complex `want`.

Comment: Yep, I think there need to be a better set of documentation on the website - unfortunately I'm uniquely unqualified to know what that documentation should be, since it's rarely helpful to me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Erik's remark about `Action` being a monad has proven to be very helpful. The problems is that action already resides within the `Rules` monad - not the other way around (Sorry Eric, for not being specific enough). The following code is on what I eventually settled.

```
import Development.Shake
import Development.Shake.Command
import Development.Shake.FilePath
import Development.Shake.Util

main :: IO ()
main = shakeArgs shakeOptions{shakeFiles="_build"} (do
  action $ do dependencies <- getDirectoryFiles "" ["*checker.py"]
              let scripts = map (\file -> "_build" </> file -<.> "sh") dependencies
              need scripts)
```

Comment: In general `want` is defined as `action . need`, so here you split up the `want` and shove in a `getDirectoryFiles`. This is the recommended way (although I think I'd use a list comprehension - but an irrelevant detail).

Answer (score 2):

`Action`, which is what [`getDirectoryFiles`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/shake-0.15.5/docs/Development-Shake.html#v:getDirectoryFiles) returns, seems to be a `Monad`, so you could use `do`-notation:

```
do
  paths <- getDirectoryFiles "" ["_build//*checkers.sh"]
  want paths
```

or just

```
getDirectoryFiles "" ["_build//*checkers.sh"] >>= want
```

or

```
want =<< getDirectoryFiles "" ["_build//*checkers.sh"]
```

**EDIT:** as per Neil Mitchell's remarks, `want` needs to be replaced with `need`.

Comment: I guess the `return` is not needed in `return $ want paths`.

Comment: oops, yes, didn't realize `want` was monadic.

Comment: Erik, your remark about `Action` being a monad has proven to be very helpful. The problems is that action already resides within the `Rules` monad - not the other way around. Sorry, for not being specific enough. Still your help has been invaluable!

Comment: This won't work because `getDirectoryFiles` is in the `Action` monad, and `want` lives in the `Rules` monad. If you make the `want` a `need` then they are in the same monad, and can be combined. If you want to lift an `Action` to a `Rules` you can use `action`.